# Jquery SetInterval Loop end again loop restart

Tags: jquery, setinterval

**How to make continue loop after certain condition meet?I mean need to restart loop again after certain condition value or range meet .**

Jquery setinterval loop condition restart after certain condition meet but below my code not working even not restart.

```
//Global  interval:any; 
    <i>public autoCheckPagination(): void {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    this.interval=setInterval(function(){
    if(pageCount<3){         //loop range till 3 
    if(count<1){
    count=5;
    pageNextClick.click();
    }
    document.getElementById("displayAutoCount").innerHTML = count+"";
   count--;
   pageCount++;
   }else if(pageCount==3){  //loop meet condition again but not restart  
   restart loop again 
  pageCount=1;
   clearInterval(this.interval);
   this.running=true;
   }

     },1000);

    }</i>
```

Setinterval loop not restart again if condition meet .

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `setTimeout` if you want to loop through a function repeatedly. The demonstration below gives you all the tools you need to code the functionality you would like.

The loop is started on the click of a button, only continues if the checkbox is checked, and can be stopped on a click of a button.

The function to stop the loop is independent, so you can call it in multiple ways or at various points in your code.

```js
// Create array for setTimeouts
var timeouts = [];


// Start loop on click of button
$("#startLoop").click(function() {

  // Add class that enables scroll
  $(this).addClass("show-scroll");

  // Stop all other timeouts
  var cleared = stopLoop();

  // Run your function
  yourFunction();

});


// Stop all timeouts when clicking stop loop button
$("#stopLoop").click(function() {

  // Stop all other timeouts
  var cleared = stopLoop();  
  console.log("Loop stopped by clicking button");

});


// You master function, that will repeatedly fire
function yourFunction() {

  // Demonstrate to user loop is continuing
  $("#dots").append(".");

  // Check if the checkbox is still checked
  if ($('#continueCheck').prop('checked')) {

    // Start a new setTimeout to continue loop
    timeouts.push(setTimeout(yourFunction, 1000));

  } else {

    // Stop the loop
    stopLoop();
    console.log("Loop stopped as checkbox is not checked.");

  }

}


// Indepenent function to end all timeouts
function stopLoop() {

  // Clear all setTimeouts
  for (var i = 0; i < timeouts.length; i++) {
    clearTimeout(timeouts[i]);
  }

  return true;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="startLoop">Start Loop</button>
<button id="stopLoop">Stop Loop</button>

<input type="checkbox" id="continueCheck" checked/> Continue loop

<hr>

<div id="dots"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

not restarted because you need to call `autoCheckPagination()` when`pageCount == 3`

```
else if (pageCount == 3) {
  pageCount = 1;
  clearInterval(this.interval);
  this.running = true;
  autoCheckPagination(); // call it again here
}
```

Comment: When calling above method I'm getting error like:core.js:1673 ERROR TypeError: this.autoCheckPagination is not a function

Comment: how you call `autoCheckPagination()` outside the function? call it like that.

Comment: I'm calling function inside function (like recursion)